# Use a shell variable in awk

Tags: bash, awk, variable

Here is my script (to find the files that contain a specified pattern):

```
find . -type f \
    -exec awk -v vawk="$1" '/'"$vawk"'/ {c++} c>0 { print ARGV[1]; exit 0 } END { if (! c) {exit 1}}' \{\} \;
```

I would like to use my script with an argument §:

```
MyScript.sh pattern
```

My problem is that I don't manage to put the `$1` variable in `awk`.

When I try to debug my script

```
bash -x MyScript.sh pattern
```

Here is the output :

```
+ find . -type f -exec awk -v vawk=pattern '// {c++} c>0 {print ARGV[1] ; exit 0 } END { if (! c) {exit 1}}' '{}' ';'
```

The `$vawk` variable seems to be empty.

Any idea?

Comment: See [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You seem to be confusing awk variables and shell variables.  `awk -v vawk="$1"` creates an *awk* variable called `vawk`, yet you are trying to use *shell* syntax (`$vawk`).  This doesn't work because the shell doesn't have a variable called `vawk`.  I think what you want is

```
awk -v vawk="$1" '$0 ~ vawk { c++ } # ...'
#                      ^ awk variable syntax
```

Comment: Note that `awk` expands the C-like escape sequences in `$1`, so that approach doesn't work if `$1` may contain backslash characters (common for regexps). You may use the `ENVIRON` awk special array instead.

Comment: In GNU awk 4.2+, that's also some form of DoS vulnerability (try for instance with `$1` being `@/x*{1,20000}/`)

Answer (score 13):

<sup>Reproduced from [this now closed as *duplicate* question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56128/external-variable-in-awk) as it includes warnings on the limitations of awk variable passing which one might find useful.</sup>

A shell variable is just that: *a **shell** variable*. If you want to turn it into a *awk* variable, you need a syntax such as:

```sh
awk -v x="$x" '$2 == x {print $1}' infile
```

or

```sh
awk '$2 == x {print $1}' x="$x" infile
```

However, those suffer from a problem: escape sequences are expanded in them.

Also, with GNU `awk` 4.2 or above, [if `$x` starts with `@/` and ends in `/`, it's treated as a regexp type of variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Strong-Regexp-Constants)).

So, for instance if the shell variable contains the two characters *backslash* and *n*, the awk variable will end up containing the *newline* character and with gawk 4.2+, if it contains `@/foo/`, the awk variable will contain `foo` and be of type `regexp`. Worse, if it's `@/(xxxxx){1,20000}/` for instance, gawk will hog one CPU for hours or until memory exhaustion trying to compile that regexp, making it some form of DoS vulnerability.

Another approach (but which like for `-v` requires a POSIX awk or nawk (as opposed to the 1970's awk still found as `/bin/awk` in Solaris)) is to use environment variables:

```sh
x="$x" awk '$2 == ENVIRON["x"] {print $1}' infile
```

Another approach (still with newer awks) is to use the ARGV array in awk:

```sh
awk -- 'BEGIN {x = ARGV[1]; delete ARGV[1]}
  $2 == x {print $1}' "$x" infile
```

Also beware that whether you use `ARGV`/`ENVIRON`/`-v` or `var=value` arguments, the corresponding string will be considered as a *numeric string* if it's shaped like a number (with the range of recognised number formats varying with the implementation).

It's important, because in that `$2 == ENVIRON["VAR"]` above for instance, it will be a string comparison¹ if `$VAR` is for instance `foo` or `1f2`, but a numeric comparison if it's `1e2` or `1.1` (or possibly `inf`, `0xff`  depending on the `awk` implementation and version), assuming `$2` also looks numeric. So `10.0e1`, `100` and `1e2` would all be considered equal.

Doing:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {var = "" ENVIRON["VAR"]}'
```

Would make sure the `var` `awk` variable is always considered as a string, even if the `$VAR` shell variable looks like a number.

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {var = 0 + ENVIRON["VAR"]}'
```

Would convert it to a number (at least the leading part of it that can be interpreted as a number).

---

<sup>¹ or `strcoll()` comparison with some implementations (as used to be required by POSIX), that is, `a == b` where either `a` or `b` or both are a string would return true if `a` and `b` have same sorting order.</sup>