# external variable in awk

Tags: awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use a script parameter in awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50044/use-a-script-parameter-in-awk)

I have a script, in which a script snippet is

```
x=3
awk '$2=$x{print $1}' infile
```

the external variable is x,

but it prompts an error in awk

so in this situation,how to make awk run successfully?

thanks!

Answer (score 7):

A shell variable is just that: *a **shell** variable*. If you want to turn it into a *awk* variable, you need a syntax such as:

```
awk -v x="$x" '$2 == x {print $1}' infile
```

or

```
awk '$2 == x {print $1}' x="$x" infile
```

However, those suffer from a problem: escape sequences are expanded in them (and with GNU `awk` 4.2 or above, [if `$x` starts with `@/` and ends in `/`, it's treated as a regexp type of variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Strong-Regexp-Constants)).

So, for instance if the shell variable contains the two characters *backslash* and *n*, the awk variable will end up containing the *newline* character (and with gawk 4.2+, if it contains `@/foo/`, the awk variable will contain `foo` and be of type `regexp`).

Another approach (but which requires a POSIX awk or nawk (as opposed to the original awk as still found on a few odd Unices)) is to use environment variables:

```
x="$x" awk '$2 == ENVIRON["x"] {print $1}' infile
```

Another approach (still with newer awks) is to use the ARGV array in awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {x = ARGV[1]; delete ARGV[1]}
  $2 == x {print $1}' "$x" infile
```

Comment: As far as I know, `ARGV` is actually a POSIX feature, it's just defined differently in `gawk`.

Comment: @ChrisDown Yes, both `ARGV` and `ENVIRON` are POSIX but not in the original awk, sorry if I wasn't clear about that. How is it different in `gawk`?

Comment: `gawk` includes unrecognised options into `ARGV`, whereas POSIX `awk` doesn't.

Comment: @ChrisDown, I think you're referring to the case where awk is called with `-f` as in `awk -f script.awk arg1 arg2...` where GNU awk doesn't need a `--` to mark the end of options if arg1 starts with a `-` but is not a valid option in that particular version of `awk`. But that's not relevant to this matter, and I would definitely not rely on that behavior (I would include the `--` nevertheless).

Answer (score 2):

You can't use external variables in `awk` directly, you have to import them as `awk` variables first.

```
x=3
awk -v foo="$x" '$2=foo{print $1}' infile
```