# Why is this variable not getting passed to awk?

Tags: shell, shell-script, awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [external variable in awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56128/external-variable-in-awk)

How do I pass this variable below?

This doesn't work:

```
fname=testfile.txt
lsof | awk '/deleted/&&/$fname/ {print $4}'  *----no output*
```

While this works:

```
lsof | awk '/deleted/&&/testfile.txt/ {print $4}'
3r
```

Comment: use double quotes instead of single quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because shell variables are not expanded in single quotes. Use `awk` with `-v` to pass the pattern into `awk` like so:

```
fname=testfile.txt
lsof | awk -v pattern="$fname" '/deleted/ && $0 ~ pattern { print $4 }'
```