# Conflicting input and pipe variables inside a shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

I have the following script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
cat $1.txt | awk "{cmd=\"pwgen 10 1\"; cmd | getline pass; print substr($0, 1, length($0) -1) \">> ~/dresses/whole-dresses-shape/$1-\" pass \".jpg\"; close(cmd);}" | bash
```

Inside the `awk "{}"` command, the `$0` variable is supposed to refer to the line being currently read from `cat $1.txt`. However, when used from inside a script file, `$0` takes the value of the name of the file being executed.

How can I make sure that the `substr()` function takes the output from `cat` in this example?

Desired workflow:

- user enters `./myscript.sh hello`
- `$1` takes `hello` value
- each line read from `cat` is assigned to what is currently displayed as  `$0`

Comment: I tried exactly that, and the problem then becomes that it is `$1` which is not right anymore. It becomes a literal $1, instead of recalling the variable. Any way to escape this?

Comment: found a way to "escape" variables within single-quotes (well, sort-of) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variables-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
variable="but put shell variable in double quotes"

echo 'Put most of the awk script in single quotes so that $s are not expanded, '"$variable"', then continue in single quotes.'
```

However, please, read @Paul_Pedant's comment, about injecting code in to a program.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted, but it's the solution I ended up going with.

Comment: It's not good because it injects shell text directly into the awk program itself. So a bad content for $variable can throw an awk syntax error, or even put in spurious valid awk commands. If you pass variables in using -v, they will be constrained to be plain variables, not arbitrarily complex in-line code.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of ways to do it more cleanly (the use of `printf` in place of `print` + string concatenation is a matter of personal preference - I find that it is more readable in this case).

1. export the value of `$1` and use the awk `ENVIRON` array ex.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   export var="$1"

   cat "$1.txt" | awk '
     BEGIN{cmd="pwgen 10 1"} 
     {
       cmd | getline pass; 
       printf "%s >> ~/dresses/whole-dresses-shape/%s-%s.jpg\n", substr($0, 1, length($0) -1), ENVIRON["var"], pass;
       close(cmd);
     }
   '
   ```
2. use the command line `-v` option to pass the value of `$1` ex.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   cat "$1.txt" | awk -v var="$1" '
     BEGIN{cmd="pwgen 10 1"} 
     {
       cmd | getline pass; 
       printf "%s >> ~/dresses/whole-dresses-shape/%s-%s.jpg\n", substr($0, 1, length($0) -1), var, pass;
       close(cmd);
     }
   '
   ```

Both of these replace the outer "soft" quotes with 'hard' quotes. A side-benefit is that it frees up a layer of quoting in case you wish to protect the *output* strings from word-splitting (probably good practice - since you are apparently piping the result to a shell), ex.

```
printf "\"%s\" >> ~\"/dresses/whole-dresses-shape/%s-%s.jpg\"\n"
```

For a discussion of `-v` versus `ENVIRON` please see

- [external variable in awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56141/65304)

Answer (score 0):

I would have used single quotes for the awk.
Not tested

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $1.txt | awk '{cmd="pwgen 10 1"; cmd | getline pass; print substr($0, 1, length($0) -1) ">> ~/dresses/whole-dresses-shape/'$1'-" pass ".jpg"; close(cmd);}' | bash
```

Comment: The embedded single-quotes around $1 break it: they get $1 from the shell, not from the awk input. But then that whole print is longing to be a printf with a proper format and two args.

Comment: No it is the trick. He wants $1 as shell argument.