# How to expand variable within a single-quoted argument?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, quoting, variable-substitution

I am trying to perform the following without luck:

```
SORT_BY='-k3,3r -k2,2 -k1,1r'
awk 'NR<4{print $0;next}{print $0 | sort '"${SORT_BY}"' -t"~"}'
```

I have tried with all sorts of quotes, unquote, etc.. but there is always a problem on awk

```
awk: illegal statement
```

How should I do the expansion>

Comment: Perhaps https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56128/external-variable-in-awk ?

Comment: But there's must be a way to do it in shell expansion time, so its agnostic to what awk literals are doing

Comment: @Whimusical You can most definitely _do_ it, it's just not a very good idea to do so. Note that the error that you get is not related to the expansion of the variable, but to the `sort` command, which `awk` knows nothing about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk isn't shell. You can't call UNIX tools like `sort` directly from awk any more than you could directly call them from a C program.

This would make what you're trying to do function:

```
SORT_BY='-k3,3r -k2,2 -k1,1r'
awk 'NR<4{print; next} {print | "sort -t\"~\" '"${SORT_BY}"'"}'
```

but it's not at all clear that that's a good idea.

Guessing that what you're trying to do is print 3 header lines unsorted and then the rest of the data sorted, this might be the best approach since, other than setting awks output separator and sorts input separator to the same character, it completely decouples awk from the sorting, doesn't require awk to spawn a shell, and will work whether the input is coming from a pipe or a file since it doesn't require opening the input twice:

```
sep='~'
awk -v OFS="$sep" '{print (NR>3), NR, $0}' file |
sort -t "$sep" -k1,1n -k2,2n -k5,5r -k4,4 -k3,3r |
cut -d "$sep" -f3-
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables are not expanded in single quoted strings.  There's no way around this.

In this case, you want to output the three first lines of your data as is, and sort the rest.  For simplicity, I would do this with

```
sort_opts=( -k3,3r -k2,2 -k1,1r )

{  head -n 3 file
   awk 'NR > 3' file | sort "${sort_opts[@]}" -t '~'  } >newfile
```

If you feel that you really want to do the sorting from within `awk`, and assuming that `$IFS` remains unchanged with a space as its first character:

```
sort_opts=( -k3,3r -k2,2 -k1,1r )

awk -v sort_opts="${sort_opts[*]}" '
    BEGIN { sortcmd = sprintf("sort %s -t \"~\"", sort_opts) }
    NR <= 3 { print; next } { print | sortcmd }' file >newfile
```

This gives the sorting options to `awk` using `-v` on the command line, the `BEGIN` block creates the sorting command to use as a string in the `sortcmd` variable, and this is then used in the last block (triggered for lines 4 on-wards).

Note that when using `print` with a pipe in `awk`, the right hand side of the pipe must be a string representing the shell command to pipe to. This is not the case in your code, which is why you get an "illegal statement" error.

---

When values that you need to import into `awk` contains backslashes, you may want to use an environment variable instead (to avoid having to double up each backslash):

```
sort_opts=( -k3,3r -k2,2 -k1,1r )

SORT_OPTS="$sort_opts[*]" awk '
    BEGIN { sortcmd = sprintf("sort %s -t \"~\"", ENVIRON["SORT_OPTS"]) }
    NR <= 3 { print; next } { print | sortcmd }' file >newfile
```

Comment: But what I mean is, I am in a script, and I am constructing the literal that represents awk argument, it must be a way to do the expansion through the shell, out of the awk domain. Why something like awk 'blablabla'"${MY_OPTS}"' blablabla' does not work? (see that I am closing first single quote and opening a double quote on my var). I am just assuming that the expansion is done before the eval of the command.

Comment: @Whimusical That would constitute a potential code injection vulnerability. The `awk` tool has a few specific ways for importing values of shell variables. Modifying the actual `awk` code itself by injecting a shell variable into the code is unsafe.