# finding the highest character length in each column using a loop and awk

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, scripting, for

I am trying to create a script that goes through a document and finds the highest character length in a column and return it. This script returns 78,78,78,78 when, what im aiming for is 10,11,14,51

```
for ((i=1;i<=4;i++)); do
  awk -F"|" '{ print length($i) }' contact_d.csv | sort -nr | sed '1!d';
done
```

`contact_d.csv` contains this: (please note dummy data) and its a sample

```
Barrera|Wilkinson|(09) 1466 1886|eu@dignissim.co.uk
Hopkins|Sellers|(07) 3814 2364|faucibus.orci@libero.co.uk
Hunter|Calderon|(01) 3984 0139|Proin@Uttincidunt.ca
```

Does anyone have any insight as to why the for loop isn't returning what I am aiming for?

Comment: ill do that now, sorry quite new to this

Comment: Inside your awk scriptlet, `i` is never assigned a value, so `$i` is always `$0` - hence you will get the lengths of the whole record at every iteration. But shell looping over an awk command is rarely a good option.

Comment: For your sample file, what would you like the script to return? 18, 26, 20?

Comment: @steeldriver I tried that just then it just returned 78. my aim with the scrip is to use the loop to go through each feel and find the highest length of each field. I did it manually and the results where as follows 10 11 14 51. I just can't see wy it didnt work?

Comment: ideally to return the row that has that highest character count for each Column @Quasímodo

Comment: @user419771 I don't know what "that" you are referring to - however to pass the value of shell variable `$i` into awk, you can add `-v i="$i"`. See for example [external variable in awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56141/65304)

Comment: thanks for getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
awk -F'|' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {len=length($i); if (len>lval[i]) {lval[i]=len; lpos[i]=FNR;}}} END{for (i in lval) printf("Longest value of column %d: %d (line %d)\n",i,lval[i],lpos[i])}' contact_d.csv
```

For the above example, it returns

```
Longest value of column 1: 7 (line 1)
Longest value of column 2: 9 (line 1)
Longest value of column 3: 14 (line 1)
Longest value of column 4: 26 (line 2)
```

- This script will, for every line, loop over all fields (from 1 to `NF`, the number of fields) and see if the length of the field (temporarily stored in a variable `l`) is greater than the longest length found so far, which is stored in an array variable `lval` under the index of the field (=column) number.
- On the first line, `lval` is not yet initialized, and *it will behave as if* all `lval[i]` were 0 (in reality, it is more complex than that).
- If the length of the field `i` on the current line is longer than the value stored in `lval[i]`, the script will store the current length of the field in `lval[i]` and the current line number (which is accessible through the "automatic" variable `FNR`) into the array variable `lpos`.
- At the end of the file (`END` condition), it will print the longest length and corresponding position for all columns. I use the construct `for (i in lval)` which loops over all *indices* present in the array `lval`, so I don't have to save the number of columns in an extra variable (as would be necessary for something like `for (i=1;i<=ncols;i++)` - *in the `END` block, the concept of "number of fields" becomes somewhat ill-defined although in practice `awk` will often use the corresponding values for the last line of the file when accessed*).

Note that it is rarely necessary to call `awk` in a shell loop; it can do most of the things you would need a loop for by itself.

As for the reason why your original attempt failed, you are trying to feed a shell variable (`$i`) to an `awk` script whose code is enclosed in single quotes (as is recommended), but the single quotes turn off the interpretation of shell variables (and even if not, it would not have worked like that).