# Define a variable to awk pattern matching from bash

Tags: shell, awk, regular-expression, quoting

I am trying to grab 100 lines after the text "time: X" with X in {0,40,80,...,200}. Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
start=1
end=5
for i in $(seq $start $end);do 
  j=$(($i*40))
  awk '/time: $j/{for(i=1;i<=100;i++}{getline;print}}' file > fileX-$j.txt
done
```

However this doesn't seem to work. My question specifically is about variable $j and how I need to define it right after '/time: ...'

For example, I have a file named 'file':

```
time: 1
1 2 3 
1 33 1 
2 31 4
time: 40
2 1 3 
9 8 77
1 3 4
```

I'd like to make 2 separate files in this case; first one containing

```
1 2 3 
1 33 1 
2 31 4
```

and second one with:

```
1 2 3 
1 33 1 
2 31 4
```

I tried passing on $j as a variable as mazs mentioned but still gives me empty files. Here is how i did:

```
awk -v jj=$j '/time: jj/{for(i=1;i<3;i++){getline;print}}' file > fileX-$j.txt
```

Comment: You don't do it like that: `awk` has a command line option for passing variables - see [Use a script parameter in awk](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50044/use-a-script-parameter-in-awk)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us an example of your input and your desired output. The main issue is that `$j` is not expanded in the awk script but we could give a better solution if you explain what you are trying to do. This sort of thing is rarely a good match for bash .

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems. The first is that the shell doesn't expand `$j` inside single quotes: `'$j'` tells the shell that you want the string `$j`, not the value of the variable `j`.

In this case, because the value only contains digits, you could put it outside of single quotes:

```
awk '/time: '"$j"'/{for(i=1;i<=100;i++}{getline;print}}' file > fileX-"$j".txt
```

Note that if the value of `j` contained regexp special characters (`.`, `*`, etc.) then those characters would be interpreted as such. For example

```
j='2*3'
awk '/foo '"$j"' bar/'
```

the script would print lines containing things like `foo 3 bar`, `foo 23 bar`, `foo 223 bar`, etc. and not `foo 2*3 bar`. And if there was a `/` in the value then awk would see the end of the regex matching construct; for example

```
j='2/3'
awk '/foo '"$j"' bar/'
```

would result in awk complaining that the sequence of tokens `/foo 2/`, `3`, `bar`, `/` is not syntactically correct.

You can define a variable for an awk with the `-v` command line option:

```
j='a\tb'
awk -v j="$j" '{print j}'
```

Note that this performs backslash expansion on the value of `j`. For example, the snippet above replaces each line by `a↦b` where `↦` is a tab character.

But that doesn't directly work in your case, because awk doesn't expand variables inside `/…/`: `/foo/` matches the string `foo`, not the value of the variable `foo`. To use a variable in a regular expression match, you would need to use the `match` function:

```
awk -v j="$j" 'match($0, "time: "+j) {for(i=1;i<=100;i++}{getline;print}}' file > fileX-"$j".txt
```

This one works for values of `j` that don't contain a backslash; a slash is ok. For example, with `j` set to `a/b*c`, this would match lines like `time: a/c`, `time: a/bc`, etc. With `j` set to `\t`, this would match lines containing `time:` followed by a space and a tab.

To pass the value of a shell variable to awk, no matter what the value is, pass it through the environment.

```
export j
awk 'match($0, "time: "+j) {for(i=1;i<=100;i++}{getline;print}}' file > fileX-"$j".txt
```

or, to avoid having `j` stay in the environment for the rest of the script:

```
j="$j" awk 'match($0, "time: "+j) {for(i=1;i<=100;i++}{getline;print}}' file > fileX-"$j".txt
```

And if you wanted to search for a literal string, rather than for a regular expression, you could use the `index` function instead of `match`. For example

```
j='a*b'
awk 'index($0, "time: "+j)'
```

prints lines containing `time: a*b`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass the $j shell variable to awk:

```
awk -v jj="$j" '...'
```

Note that this assumes that the value of the variable does not contain backslashes, as the argument to `awk -v` undergoes backslash expansion.

Comment: and to use it, something like: `awk -v j=$j '$0 ~ "time: " j { for.....`

Comment: This is only half the issue.