# Expanding awk -v variable

Tags: awk

When I run `awk '/2017-12-05T12:07:33.941Z/{y=1;next}y' file.json` it works as expected, printing everything after the timestamp.

I'm trying to follow the syntax in this [Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50044/use-a-script-parameter-in-awk) but my syntax isn't expanding right:

```
awk -v last_log="$last_log" '/{print last_log}/{y=1;next}y' file.txt
```

Also trying:

```
awk -v last_log="$last_log" '/$0 ~ last_log/{y=1;next}y' file.txt
```

---

*Example, given the following input, return all logs after last processed( `2017-12-05T12:07:33.941Z`):*

```
{ "name": "PeriodicWork", "hostname": "myHost", "pid": 12189, "level": 20, "msg": "Executing [CheckFailedTask NodeId=8]", "time": "2017-12-05T10:07:33.941Z", "v": 0 }

{ "name": "PeriodicWork", "hostname": "myHost", "pid": 12188, "level": 50, "msg": "Executing [CheckFailedTask NodeId=8]", "time": "2017-12-05T12:07:33.941Z", "v": 0 }

{ "name": "PeriodicWork", "hostname": "myHost", "pid": 12187, "level": 40, "msg": "Executing [CheckFailedTask NodeId=8]", "time": "2017-12-05T12:57:33.941Z", "v": 0 }
```

Comment: what's the `file.json` content?

Comment: `/{print last_log}/` will not expand your variable... use `$0 ~ last_log`

Comment: @Sundeep updated question

Comment: no, just `$0 ~ last_log` without the `/`s

Comment: @Sundeep ok just tried it and it didn't work. If I remove the `/`s how will it expand into the original command I posted `awk '/2017-12-05T12:07:33.941Z/{y=1;next}y' file.json`?

Comment: `$0 ~ last_log` will do the regex matching... give us sample input and output so that we can test... if you want proof, check `seq 18 | awk -v r='4' '$0 ~ r{f=2; next} f && f--'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, I don't think it was your intention to treat `2017-12-05T12:07:33.941Z` as a regexp, (where `.` would match any character instead of just `.`).

For a substring match, as opposed to a regexp match, you can use `index()`:

```
LAST_LOG="$last_log" awk 'index($0, ENVIRON["LAST_LOG"]) {y=1;next};y' file.txt
```

I prefer `ENVIRON` over `-v` as `-v` mangles the content of the variable if it contains backslashes ([as already noted in the Q&A you referenced](/a/56190)).

About why yours fail:

```
/{print last_log}/
```

as a *condition*, matches on records that match the `{print last_log}` regular expression, but that's not a valid regular expression (`{` is a regexp operator that needs to be used as `{2}` or `{1,5}`...).

In:

```
/$0 ~ last_log/
```

again, that tries to match on `$0 ~ last_log` as a regexp. Here that means on lines that contain `0 ~ last_log` *after* the end of the line (`$`), so will never match. You probably meant:

```
awk -v last_log="$last_log" '$0 ~ last_log {y=1;next};y' file.txt
```

That is where the *condition* is the `$0 ~ last_log` expression as opposed to just one regexp `/foo/`. `/foo/` is short for `$0 ~ /foo/`, that is match the `foo` regexp against the full record.

You can do `$0 ~ var`, but you can't do `var` alone, as it wouldn't be a regexp matching, but an expression that resolves to true if `var` contains a number other than 0, or a non-empty non-numerical string (like for your `y` one)

Comment: thanks, that answers my specific question. Off hand any idea how to stop my format from breaking the `awk` syntax? I'm getting `awk: cmd. line:1: LAST_LOG=2017-12-05T12:07:33.941Z
awk: cmd. line:1:                       ^ syntax error`

Comment: In this case I'll just convert the time to a unix timestamp that'll make it easier to process anyways.

Comment: ah, I guess I can't convert to a timestamp without a lot of processing because I don't control producing the log files.

Comment: @Philip, see edit.

Comment: Sorry my mistake it was working, I broke something else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### With awk intervals

From last_log to eof can also be obtained by "," operator;

```
 awk  '$0 ~ last, 0'  last="$last_log" file.txt
```

With last_log values like the one presented

```
 awk "/$last_log/,0" file.txt
```

Probably we need to add `| tail -n +1`

#### With Sed:

```
sed  "1,/$last_log/d"  file.txt
```

Comment: That prints the first matching line though which it seems the OP wanted to skip.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, your are right. ` | tail -n +2` ?

Comment: Or `awk 'NR==1, $0 ~ last{next}; 1'` though that wouldn't be simpler than the OP's `$0 ~ last {y=1;next};y`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `awk "1,/$last_log/{next} 1" `

Comment: Those are best avoided as it's a command injection vulnerability if the content of the variable is not under your control. It's just as dangerous as passing variable data to `eval`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, right again. The same problem appear with the other uses of `"$last_log"`

Comment: In the other cases (`LAST_LOG="$last_log" awk...` or `awk -v last_log="$last_log"`), except for bugs in awk implementations, you wouldn't get a command injection vulnerability. You could get a DoS in the regexp case for values of regexps that are very expensive like a `(x*){5000}` that eats all your memory and time of one CPU with GNU awk, but normally not arbitrary command execution.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, thank you. (In this situation this does not constitutes a problem, but in other situations it may be dangerous)