# Adding a column to the start of a .tsv file in a loop?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

Hi I'm having a bit of trouble when using **awk** to add a column at the start of a .tsv file that i'm creating within a loop.

My code is as follows (can ignore the rest of the loop):

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
curl *URL.org* > ./folder/$line.tsv
sleep 60
awk '{print "$line\t" $0}' ./folder/$line.tsv > $line.tabbed
done < ./folder/<filetoread>.txt
```

So basically I have this loop that I'm using to create a tsv file from a curl command, and using the $line variable to create a file with this. The file read is simply a list of single word identifiers;

```
RUIAHT48
RUIAHT49
etc.
```

I thought I could use **awk** to append this $line variable to create a new column in each of the newly created files.

Output before awk command;

```
$line  col1 col2  col3  col4    col5
$line  CLV_M   19     25    False   False
$line  CLV_P   59     63    False   False
$line  DEG_N   1      3     False   False
$line  DOC_C   10     14    False   False
```

Desired output;

```
new      col1   col2    col3    col4    col5
<value>  CLV_M  19      25      False   False
<value>  CLV_P  59      63      False   False
<value>  DEG_N  1       3       False   False
<value>  DOC_C  10      14      False   False
```

Where the new column is all the same value but the actual value instead of literally just "$line". Where am I going wrong here? Should I actually be using awk or another command with a simpler way?

Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a script parameter in awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50044/use-a-script-parameter-in-awk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the variable to `awk` using the `-v` switch:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    curl *URL.org* > "./folder/$file.tsv"
    sleep 60
    awk -v line="$line" '{ OFS = "\t"; print line,$0}' "./folder/$line.tsv" > "$line.tabbed"
done < ./folder/<filetoread>.txt
```

You can add `\t` to your output as you have done in the OP, but I would do it using the `OFS` option of `awk`.

Additionally I'm not sure what you're doing but are you aware that `$file.tsv` doesn't appear to be used?  I think that should be `$line.tsv`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've had a play around and the outcome is the new column just saying `line`, instead of `$line`. Also yeah apologies it was meant to be `line.tsv`, thanks for noticing.

Comment: Scratch that. I just removed the two sets of `" "` around the set awk variable `"$line"` and the print `"line"` and its worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: You should not remove the quotes as that will introduce security vulnerabilities to your code.  I really don't think the quotes were causing an issue.

Comment: Surely if I don't remove the quotes around the print `"line"` then it would just add  the word line to the new column? Which is what I was getting before I removed them. I'll have a play around and see if it effects anything but for now that seems to have worked.

Comment: @maltedg: Sorry yes that is correct but you should not remove them around the variable assignment `-v line="$line"` should stay in quotes.

Comment: Yeah apologies, I had that at the start but obviously found that it came out wrong. Appreciate your help, thanks alot!