# awk argument $1,$2 conflict with bash input arguments

Tags: linux, bash, awk, arguments

I would like to add some awk commands to a bash script.  The bash script takes a few inputs, and inputs are passed by `$1, $2 and etc`.  When I call `awk`, I also want to use `$1` to define a position in the table, how can I do it?

`example.sh`

```
#! /user/bin/bash
arg=$1
outfile=$2
awk -F, -OFS, -v '{$2="$arg"; print}' > outfile
```

In this script, `$2` is resolved to `$outfile`.  How can I avoid this?

Comment: Just like you did since $1 and $2 in awk are totally unrelated to $1 and $2 in shell (no, $2 in the awk script does NOT resolve to $outfile) but see https://stackoverflow.com/q/19075671/1745001 for how to handle `arg`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few errors in your `awk` command.

The following will import `$arg` as the `awk` variable `arg`:

```
awk -F , -v OFS=, -v arg="$arg" '{ $2 = arg; print }' >"$outfile"
```

`$2` can impossibly be interpreted as the second positional parameter here or in your code since it occurs in single quotes, and the shell does not expand single quoted variables.

`OFS` and `arg` (both are `awk` variables) are set with `-v` on the command line.  You don't use `-v` to set `OFS` and you use `-v` in the wrong way in front of the actual `awk` code.  This would have given you an error (which you don't mention).  In fact `-OFS,` with GNU `awk` means "turn on optimisation and set the input field separator to the string `S,`".

Note that if `$arg` (the shell variable) contains backslashes that you need to preserve, then it's better to pass the value through the environment instead since these would otherwise be interpreted by `awk`:

```
arg="$arg" awk -F , -v OFS=, '{ $2 = ENVIRON["arg"]; print }' >"$outfile"
```

The output file is presumably supposed to be `$outfile`, not `outfile`.

Related:

- [Pass shell variable as a /pattern/ to awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120788/pass-shell-variable-as-a-pattern-to-awk)
- [Use a shell variable in awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50044/use-a-shell-variable-in-awk)
- (and many others)