# Substituting string in a file by another string with leading zeros in linux

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I have a text file `filename` for which I want to substitute a certain numerical string in row `row_num`by another one that starts with leading zeros. That row is:

```
"uuid": "34ba55d4-42fd-448e-862a-f1515"
```

And I would like to substitute the last four digits so that **the desired end result is**:

```
"uuid": "34ba55d4-42fd-448e-862a-f0155"
```

The command I am using is:

```
gawk  'NR=='$row_num'{gsub(/'1515'/,'0155')};1' filename > tmp && mv tmp filename
```

The problem is that linux interprets 0155 as an octal number due to the leading zero and returns:

```
"uuid": "34ba55d4-42fd-448e-862a-f109"
```

Resolving the interpretation by adding `10#` to `0155` does not resolve my issue because then it is evaluated and the zero is avoided, yielding:

```
"uuid": "34ba55d4-42fd-448e-862a-f155"
```

**How can I make the substitution so that I obtain the desired output?**

I would like the solution to be general so that it also works in the case where the first element is nonzero, for which my provided solution does work.

Comment: Why are you exposing the pattern / replacement to interpretation by the shell at all? instead of something like `gawk -v row_num="$row_num" 'NR==row_num {sub(/1515/,"0155")};1' filename`

Comment: In this case you are right. I used the single quotes because I may want to use the replacement when the strings are stored in variables. E.g. val=1515 and val2=0155. Then, I would need to use the single quotes to evaluate them right? This version of your response actually worked for me: ` gawk -v row_num="$row_num" 'NR==row_num {sub(/'val'/,"'$val2'")};1'  filename`. Thank you!

Comment: If you need to pass shell variables for the pattern and/or replacement, you should do so using `-v` like I showed for the `row_num` or use `ENVIRON` or `ARGV`. See for example [Use a shell variable in awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56190/65304)