# Append text to flagged output of awk

Tags: bash, awk, regular-expression, output

I have a function that takes a filename. It then runs a command and filters the output (exclusive) between two patterns, then it outputs comma separated values with the filename output of the command.

Here is the function and the expected output:

```bsh
get_cons_obs() {
    local line="${1}"
    "command" -i "${line}" 2>&1 \
        | awk '/^ERROR$/{print "ERROR"} /^START$/{flag=1;next} /^END$/{flag=0} flag' \
        | xargs printf "${line},%s\n"
}
```

```
file01,thing01
file01,thing02
file01,thing03
.
.
.
```

Is it possible to combine `awk` command and the `xargs printf` command? I can't seem to append the "flagged" lines with the `$line` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to pass the shell variable `line` into awk so that you can print it when `flag` is non-zero

Ex.

```
awk -v line="$line" '. . . flag {printf "%s,%s\n", line, $0}'
```

See also

- [Use a shell variable in awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50044/use-a-shell-variable-in-awk)

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Below command and it worked fine

```
awk '/pattern1/,/pattern2/{print $0","FILENAME}' filename
```