# How to perform artihmetic operation in awk if condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am working on checking if a particular file existing in the directory is older than 30 mins or not.

```
curr_epch=`date +%s`
curr_epch_buff=`expr $curr_epch - 1800`


ls -l --time-style=+"%s" | grep .part |  awk '{ if (($6 >= $curr_epch_buff)) print $6 }'
```

However the above code is giving me results irrespective of the condition mentioned.

To debug it, when i tried to take a difference between these 2 values also I am not getting expected results, instead the value in **$6** is getting printed as it  is:

```
ls -l --time-style=+"%s" | grep .part |  awk '{ print (expr $6 - $curr_epch_buff) }'
```

However if i try to subtract a static number using above query, its giving me expected results:

```
ls -l --time-style=+"%s" | grep .part |  awk '{ print (expr $6 - 200) }'
```

Can someone please tell me whats wrong with first and second set of codes mentioned above?

Comment: This is a variant of [Use a shell variable in awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56190/65304) - however you shouldn't be relying on parsing the output of `ls` to find files by age (use something like `find -mmin` instead)

Comment: mmin will give if file was changed in last specified mins. In my case files will be there which came just now or 10 mins before or 20 or 40. I just need to pull out files which are older than 30 mins before and not anything lesser than that. @steeldriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(...)` instead of `` `...` `` -- see
https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082
bash can do arithmetic, you don't need to call out to `expr`.
[Don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

```bsh
curr_epch_buff=$( date -d '30 minutes ago' +%s )

for file in *.part; do
    file_mtime=$( stat -c '%Y' "$file" )
    if (( file_mtime < curr_epch_buff )); then
        echo "$file is older than 30 minutes"
    fi
done
```

---

The problems with `awk '{ print (expr $6 - $curr_epch_buff) }'`:

- `curr_epch_buff` is treated as an *awk variable*. It is unset.
- in awk `$n` acts like an operator, to return the contents of the field number referenced by `n`
- in a numeric context, an unset variable is treated as the number 0
- so `$curr_epch_buff` is the same as `$0` i.e. the entire record.
- `expr` is also an unset variable
- `expr $6` is string contatenation, the result is the contents of `$6`
- `$6 - $0`

  - the record does not start with a number, it starts with the file's permission string as returned by `ls -l`
  - awk treats a string that does not start with numbers as zero

The final result is the value of `$6`

Comment: cool... I am able to get the result... Awesome. And Thanks Much for detailed explanation and help :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ -z "$(find . -name '*.part' -mmin -30)" ]
then
   echo ".part file is old"
else
   echo ".part file is recent"
fir
```

Comment: does that work? my man page for `find` says that _"find  exits with status 0 if all files are processed successfully, greater than 0 if errors occur."_, it doesn't say anything about the exit status being affected by files being found, or not found (unlike grep).

Comment: @ilkkachu you are quite right.  I'll try to correct my ways.