# awk passing variable, files with spaces

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, filenames

I am new and I have small problem and I couldn't solve it by myself. Here is the issue that I am faced with:

- I am trying to find the files with spaces in their names.

  This part is working:

  ```
    find $(pwd) -type d |grep " "
  ```
- Then I am using the `awk` to print whole file name and change it with desired group name "manually typing"

  ```
    find $(pwd) |grep " " |awk '{print "changegrp developers \""$0"\""}'
  ```
- When I try to make group name `developers` as a variable, it is not really working as expected.

  ```
    find $(pwd) |grep " " |awk group="developers" '{print "changegrp group \""$0"\""}'
  ```

I really don't understand the syntax. how it is possible that manually typed group is working and when I make it a variable, it is working. I know that kind of things can give some headaches due to forgetting one single quote or double quotes etc.

Could you please point me out where I am making wrong?

Comment: Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) to understand the main problems in your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass `group` into awk as a variable you need `-v group="developers"` and to have awk treat it as a variable (rather than a string literal) it needs to be outside the double quotes, like

```
awk -v group="developers" '{print "changegrp " group " \""$0"\""}'
```

However, you can likely avoid a lot of headaches by using something like

```
find . -type d -name '* *' -exec changegrp developers {} \;
```

or (if `changegroup` supports multiple file arguments - I am unfamiliar with the particular command)

```
find . -type d -name '* *' -exec changegrp developers {} +
```

See also

- [Use a shell variable in awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56190/65304)

Comment: Good night steeldriver, thank you for your answer. definitely your answer is the best one. To be honest, when I see the solution with the find exec combination. I said by myself, "why i thought that complicated? if I could do this operation with the simple find exec command. Anyway i forgot with the first command (with the awk) to add "| bash"  to execute the awk command. Additionally, I could pass the argument to the find exec combination as well. I want to thank you again for your great time. Highly appreciated! Have a nice night. Now I can sleep better. :)

Comment: `print "changegrp " group " \""$0"\""` should be `print "changegrp \047" group "\047 \047" $0 "\047"` so it won't fail if `$0` or `group` contains characters you don't want the shell interpreting (assuming you're generating a list of commands to be executed later by a shell). There should probably be a `--` in there too between  the command name and the arguments but that's probably overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Sidestepping both `find` and `awk`, and assuming you're interested in only directories (as per your first code snippet):

```
shopt -s globstar dotglob nullglob

for name in ./**/*' '*; do
    [[ -d $name ]] && [[ ! -L $name ]] && changegrp developers "$name"
done
```

or,

```
shopt -s globstar dotglob nullglob

for name in ./**/*' '*/; do
    [[ ! -L ${name%/} ]] && changegrp developers "$name"
done
```

This uses a simple loop to execute the `changegrp` command on each directory that have at least one space in its name.  It does so by means of the `**` globbing pattern (enabled via the `globstar` shell option in `bash`) which matches down into subdirectories.  The `nullglob` and `dotglob` shell options are used to make the shell remove unmatched patterns and to also match hidden names.

The `-L` test is used here to weed out symbolic links to directories (the `-d` test would be *true* for both directories and symbolic links to directories).

In the second variation of the code above, we pick only directories by adding a `/` at the end of the pattern.  This slash needs to be taken off for the `-L` test, which is what `${name%/}` is doing.

It would then be easy to have the string `developers` be a variable:

```
shopt -s globstar dotglob nullglob

group=developers

for name in ./**/*' '*; do
    changegrp "$group" "$name"
done
```

(This code additionally applies `changegrp` to *all* names that contain spaces in or under the current directory, as per your other code snippets in the question.)